# Efficient operations on a collection of objects using Java: Map vs Direct approach

Tags: java, performance

I'm currently working on a Java project and I have a specific scenario where I need to perform operations on a collection of objects. I'm wondering which approach would be more efficient in terms of performance.

Let's say I have an array `x` of objects of type `A`, and each object `A` has a reference to an object of type `B` as a member (`A.c.b`). I need to perform some operation on each `B` object.

Approach 1: Creating a map and then iterating over it

```java
Map<A, B> map = new HashMap<>();
for (A a : x) {
    map.put(a, a.c.b);
}

for (Map.Entry<A, B> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    entry.getValue().dosomeoperation();
}
```

Approach 2: Directly performing the operation on the objects

```java
for (A a : x) {
    a.c.b.dosomeoperation();
}
```

I understand that Approach 2 eliminates the overhead of creating and populating a map, but I'm not sure about the actual performance difference between the two approaches. Could someone with expertise shed some light on this?

In my specific case, the size of the `x` array can vary, and I'm interested in optimizing the performance of my code. It would be helpful to understand the potential performance implications of these approaches and any factors I should consider while making a decision.

Any insights or alternative suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well the performance difference is as you noted: you create an entire map unnecessarily. Otherwise (especially through your iterator), you're faced with essentially the exact same _logical_ operations. The performance difference will come down to the iterator implementation used between your "array" and your `HashMap`. You could use a stream to the same effect as that end for-loop (but everything is better than the `Map` in this case): `x.stream().map(a -> a.c.b).forEach(B::dosomeoperation);` or iterably `x.forEach(a -> a.c.b.dosomeoperation());`

Comment: In shorter words: the map exists solely to iterate over values of `B`. You can already get those values of `B` (the same way you added them to the `Map`), so why go through the extra work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Map` shown in your Question adds no value. It creates an association between the object `a` and its nested member `b`. But you already had an association of `a` to `b`: the nested field membership *is* that association.

If you are performing a single operation on a nested member field, just access that field.

No need to involve any collections. Creating a collection with no specific purpose, such as ordering/sorting, is just additional work with no benefit.

```java
for (A a : x) {
    a.c.b.dosomeoperation();
}
```

Or use streams.

```
Arrays
.stream( x )
.forEach( 
    ( A a ) -> a.c.b.dosomeoperation()
) ;
```

---

If you have a concern about some complicating factor or operation, revise your Question to explain.